# Loading the spacy german language model into a jupyter notebook

Tags: python, spacy

This is the cell in notebook:

```
#%%

!python -m spacy download de_core_news_sm
spacy_en = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
spacy_de = spacy.load('de_core_news_sm')
```

I get this error:

```
OSError: [E050] Can't find model 'de_core_news_sm'. It doesn't seem to be a shortcut link, a Python package or a valid path to a data directory.
```

I'm puzzled as I think I've followed the spacy instructions correctly.

Comment: I also get "no module spacy" when doing the python -m spacy .   How do I download a spacy model in a jupyter script ?

Comment: I tried running this on google colab and it indicated: Successfully installed de-core-news-sm-2.1.0
✔ Download and installation successful
You can now load the model via spacy.load('de_core_news_sm') : but it fails the same way.

Answer (score 2):

Once you execute

```
!python -m spacy download de_core_news_sm
spacy_de = spacy.load('de_core_news_sm')
spacy_en = spacy.load('en_core_web_sm')
```

Simply restart your runtime . From Runtime > Restart runtime .And run

```
import spacy
nlp = spacy.load('de_core_news_sm')
```

Works for me .Hope it was helpful

Answer (score 0):

if you use anaconda jupyter notebook then just run this code and problem will solve:`conda install -c conda-forge spacy-model-de_core_news_sm`